# Should these two questions about running/installing .exe files be merged?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, merge, windows

The two questions I am talking about are:

- [Why does Ubuntu fail to run .exe files? / How do I run .exe?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/259649/why-does-ubuntu-fail-to-run-exe-files-how-do-i-run-exe)
- [How can I install Windows software or games?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/988/how-can-i-install-windows-software-also-games)

They are different but they both try to achieve the same goal. Can we consider them as duplicates?

I am biased towards [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/262123/114818) by [Rafał Cieślak](https://askubuntu.com/users/705/rafal-cieslak) and would like to make that question as the master and merge the other answers from the second question.

I have already left a comment on both the questions linking to each other, but don't think it would have the desired effect.

What does the community feel and think about it? Is there any need of merger? If yes, which way?

Comment: Good question.  If they do get merged, it needs to be in to How can I install since it touches on MSI with msiexec as well.

Answer (score 1):

meh, someone did, but didn't mark this as complete...